# Is the couplet about mathematics and poetry about logocentricism and deconstructionism?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-language, deconstruction, quote, poetry

I find this couplet really interesting:

> Mathematics is the art of giving the same name to different things
>   Poetry is the art of giving different names to the same thing

[The first one is made from Poincaré, the second one is a quick response of an unknown poet to that mot.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/40304/28910) Besides being a counterpoint of each other, do they represent anything in philosophy? In particular, is the first one talking about logocentricism (there exists a signified that you can grasp), and the second one is deconstructionism (there is no signified to expect to grasp it at all)?

<sub>Also asked on reddit: [Is the couplet about mathematics and poetry about logocentricism and deconstructionism? : askphilosophy](https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/8ddvbn/is_the_couplet_about_mathematics_and_poetry_about/?st=jg6fkk9g&sh=6cdfb655)</sub>

Comment: I read it as saying that mathematics is about reducing things to number and poetry is about recovering them as complex phenomena. Something like this.

Comment: Do you care to express your thoughts on the terms as you applied them? _logocentrism_, _deconstructionism_? Or _art_ for that matter.

Comment: @xtian do you mean defining them (deconstructionism, logicentricism)? I'd use standard definitions. I think the couplet has given a definitions for math and art.

Comment: Ooker. Your post, at best, makes a claim these terms have relevance to the quote. I think it’s fair to ask you to further express your understanding of this claim. At worst you’re making a guess at relevancy, and you wish the community to discuss this simple juxtaposition. But, as you must know, SE is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @xtian I don't have much knowledge on philosophy, so my question will unavoidably be vague. I would love to fix that though. I have added a little more information, can you see it if it's better?

Comment: Ooker. Your edit introduced yet a fourth term, _signified_. From my greater experience in art and semiotics than philosophy and theory of mathematics, terms like "deconstruction" and "signifier/signified" are segregated in philosophy and absent in mathematical theory. For this reason alone I believe it's unlikely you'll get any responses, because answers will be **subjective**. If it was me, I would focus on reading--bibliography and index mining. Unfortunately, I can't offer any single starting point in mathematics. For Semiotics, maybe Handbook of Semiotics by Winfried Noth

Comment: @xtian thanks for you input, I'll check it. In the mean time, can you elaborate more on the "segregated in philosophy" bit?

Comment: Ooker. _segregated in philosophy_. By this I mean the language of semiotics, structuralism and deconstruction are not evenly distributed across the philosophical discipline--not in common usage.

Comment: @xtian no? I thought that they are major movements in philosophy?